# how can I do a jQuery swear word / bad word filter?

Tags: jquery

I know there are many arguments as to why this is a bad idea, but in my implementation I'm planning on enabling/disabling bad words in the account settings.  In other words, bad words will be visible by default, but switched off / hidden if asked.

The plan will be to send a JSON string to the client and let the client filter out the bad words.

json string

```
['swear1', 'swear2']
```

original phrase

```
this phrase includes swear1
```

final output

```
this phrase includes ****
```

this is what I've tried so far

```
    $(document).ready (function () {
        $('body').html().replace('asdf', 'ffff');
    });
```

now on a side note, I am using asp.net mvc and I "could" do this on the server side, but I was thinking that this would be better if offloaded to the client... I'm open to suggestions on this.

Comment: The JSON-string is incorrect, `w` is not unique... It should be an array like this: `{"w": ["swear"', "swear2"]}`

Comment: This code still has clbuttic syndrome though, doesn't it? That may be undesirable even for a opt-in filter

Comment: You can't. "Bad word" filters are a fundamentally flawed idea, and even the best implementations annoys users at least a dozen times with false positives for every time it actually helps. Whatever you  come up with annoys users a hundred times. See also: clbuttic. And neither can prevent even a stupid, lazy person from insulting someone else. Also, client-side validation can be easily circumvented.

Comment: @Pekka, that's why the filter is "Off" by default. Then everyone will see the text raw and unencumbered. They will forget that the system has a filter, and they won't say @$$hole because it takes too much brain power. They'll just write asshole because to them it's not being filtered.

Comment: @rock yeah, I understand that and that's fine, but as it stands, the filter is bound to turn the perfectly innocent `classic` into `cl***ic`. It would at least have to be looking for entire words I think

Comment: @delnan - why on earth would someone enable the bad word filter and then circumvent it? They can just switch it off.  My site is a public facing site much like SO. So if I want to filter out bad words I just switch it on, otherwise leave it alone.

Comment: @Pekka, yes I would absolutely want to filter whole words only and not partial words.

Comment: It's less about having it show to yourself (kudos for giving the option of disabling this misfeature), but making it show even to those who have it enabled (and yes, this is perfectly possible and a no-brainer even with the best filters).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
String.prototype.repeat = function(num){
  return new Array(num + 1).join(this);
}

var filter = ['ass', 'piss'];

$('.post').text(function(i, txt){

  // iterate over all words
  for(var i=0; i<filter.length; i++){

    // Create a regular expression and make it global
    var pattern = new RegExp('\\b' + filter[i] + '\\b', 'g');

    // Create a new string filled with '*'
    var replacement = '*'.repeat(filter[i].length);

    txt = txt.replace(pattern, replacement);
  }

  // returning txt will set the new text value for the current element
  return txt;
});
```

Working [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/haampie/xe2Zj/4/) on jsFiddle

**Edit**: Added boundaries so it won't replace words that contain the swear words. I've used double backslashes because backslashes should be escaped in a string, [see this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966535/javascript-regexp-and-boundaries).

Comment: this works great. I had to make a modification `$('body').html` instead of `$('.post').text` because using `.text` caused the output to be plain text and not html.

Comment: how would I make the regex filter whole words only?  IE: **ass** needs to be filtered but **bass** doesn't.  I tried adding `^` and `$` in the "pattern", in the "txt.replace" and also in the original JSON "filter" string. But it was to no avail. Probably because it was looking for the start of the `body` to start with "swear1" in which it obviously doesn't.

Comment: For that you'll need boundaries like this: `\b...\b`, I'll update my answer ;)

Comment: See my updated answer and the updated example jsFiddle, works fine for me (:  -- one more thing: you'll be declaring these Regular Expression objects over and over again this way, maybe it's better to just pre-compile them and their replacement in an array. That should be faster

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far, one more addition. How would I make it so that my "fiter" is actually external? IE: an external JSON content result?  I've currently got the path `http://mysite.com/generic/profanity` generating the proper json, but I'm not sure how to get the "filter" variable to use it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a lightweight function.

```
var filterWords = ["fool", "dumb", "shit", "ass", "couch potato"];
var rgx = new RegExp(filterWords.join("|"), "gi");
function wordFilter(str) {           
    return str.replace(rgx, "****");            
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So I've taken the base suggestion that @Harmen gave and I extended it into a jQuery plugin. This seems to be the best implementation that I could possibly come up with.

[jQuery.profanityFilter](https://github.com/ChaseFlorell/jQuery.ProfanityFilter)

```
$(document).profanityFilter({
    replaceWith:'#',
    customSwears: ['ass'],
    externalSwears: '/swearWords.json'
})
```

Comment: Hello , How can i prevent arabic bad words ? is it possible to using profanityFilter ?

Answer (score 1):

When moving things from server to client, you must always consider bandwidth against processing cost. Sure, having it on the client-side will minimize you processing costs, but you will waste a lot of time moving the list of bad words to the client.

Besides, having it on server may enable you to pre-process posts, for example, and only update it when a rule change, saving even more process time.

Comment: +1 - yeah I hadn't really thought of bandwidth costs with the JSON. This is a valid arguement

Comment: If caching is used (and most likely it is), the bandwidth will only be used once.

Comment: I've added my own answer to this very old question. I've written a jQuery profanity filter, and in it I pass the JSON to the client once and where possible, I store it in `localStorage`

Answer (score 0):

The JSON object you return cannot have repeated attribute names. Instead of `{ w: 'Swear1', w: 'Swear2' }` it should be `[ 'Swear1', 'Swear2' ]`.

You can parse the text to filter and wrap every occurrence of a swear word between `<span>` tags with a particular class attribute and toggle them with a function. That should be a simple approach.

Comment: sorry, I hadn't even gotten to the JSON yet, i'm more concerned about the actual replace function.

Comment: @Harmen: actually, yes. Using the same attribute name more than once will just return the last value assigned for that attribute.

Comment: It still is invalid... `[]` are meant for an array (which is a series of values only), `{}` are for an object (which is a series of keys and values)

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to iterate over all the words: for each word, check if its one of your banned words before replacing it with asterisks.

In order to do this efficiently, you'll want to store the words in a hashtable:

```
var badWords = {
    hello: true,
    goodbye: true,
};
```

Iterate over each word and then see if it is in the hashtable. (The interpretation of what comprises a "word" varies, depending on if you are just looking for characters surrounded by whitespace or other non-alpha characters.)

```
// Pseudocode
for each word in content {
    if (badWords[word]) {
        // replace word with word.length * characters
    }
}
```