# how to use external json file as a variable

Tags: jquery, json

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541070/how-can-i-do-a-jquery-swear-word-bad-word-filter) I asked how to implement a client side bad word filter.

The problem I have is that I don't want to send the masive string to the page, but rather call it from an external file.

here's the code so far

```
    var filter = ['ass']; // this is a literal JSON result
    String.prototype.repeat = function (num) {
        return new Array(num + 1).join(this);
    }

    $('body').html(function (i, txt) {
        for (var i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {

            // Create a regular expression and make it global
            var pattern = new RegExp('\\b' + filter[i] + '\\b', 'g');

            txt = txt.replace(pattern, "****");
        }

        return txt;
    });
```

But I'd like to change it to soemthing like

```
    var filter = '/generic/profanity/'; // the "profanity" page generates the exact 
                                        // same JSON result as above only in a cached
                                        // external page (it's actually generated by
                                        // an ASP.NET MVC Controller (ContentResult)
    String.prototype.repeat = function (num) {
        return new Array(num + 1).join(this);
    }

    $('body').html(function (i, txt) {
        for (var i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {

            // Create a regular expression and make it global
            var pattern = new RegExp('\\b' + filter[i] + '\\b', 'g');

            txt = txt.replace(pattern, "****");
        }

        return txt;
    });
```

but unfortunately with this, it's using `'/generic/profanity'` as a literal string for the regex rather than a reference path.

This is probably something really stupid, but how would I fix this?

#### Edit:

after @GSP's answer I'm trying this approach, and though it feels closer, it's still not working.

If I go into firebug and look at the "filter" variable in the DOM, it is represented as `['asdf']`

```
    var filter = '';

    String.prototype.repeat = function (num) {
        return new Array(num + 1).join(this);
    }

    $('.page').html(function (i, txt) {

        $.getJSON('/generic/profanity', function (data) {

            // data is the contents of the 
            filter = data;

        });

        for (var i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {

            // Create a regular expression and make it global
            var pattern = new RegExp('\\b' + filter[i] + '\\b', 'g');

            txt = txt.replace(pattern, "****");
        }

        return txt;
    });
```

Comment: Beware, this can potentially break other javascript that implemented event listeners before you run your code. In older browsers it can also potentially create memory leaks and basically create an aweful user experience all around. It's always better to implement profanity filters on the backend.

Comment: Any stored references to html elements made before you run this client side filter will also be lost since the replaced html will consist out of entirely new instances of html elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the JQuery will always be run from the browser context you will always be downloading the file anyway so this isn't going to work the way you think it is.

But, if you want to use this method you'll want to use one of the JQuery methods like $.get, or $.getJSON to get the file from your server before you parse it:

```
var filter = '';
$.getJSON('/generic/profanity', function(data) {

  // data is the contents of the 
  filter = data;

});
```

Comment: I like this solution, and it makes sense to me, however it's not working as expected.

Comment: note, the filtering should also happen in the getJSON callback since only then the filterData is available.

Comment: ah, that was it @BGerrissen. I had the getJson inside the filter function instead of the filter function inside the getJson.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about the previous topic, just perform a replace on the `filter` and make the `\` escaped (`\\`). Though not sure how you're going to use JavaScript to open a file (unless the file's hosted and you're using ajax or something to retrieve the list). JS is very sand-boxed when it comes to accessing local files.

```
var pattern = new RegExp('\\b' + filter[i].replace('\\','\\\\') + '\\b', 'g');
```

Comment: yeah, basically I'm generating the JSON in my MVC controller with content out of the database.  I want to cache the page so that I can reduce bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: [Dynamically loading an external JavaScript or CSS file](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml)

Because JSON is in general pure JavaScript the above example should work.

Comment: But there can be a better and simpler aproach for jQuery.