# Word Replacement with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks in advance for the help.

I have been fooling around with browser extensions (a novice) and I have been trying to figure out some word swapping issues; specifically, I am trying to do something akin to a [rebus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus).

I tested my code out on just a plain text page, and it works.  But then, when making it an extension, it basically loses the styling on the page and turns it into text only.

I have been looking for a more unobtrusive way to swap a word like "shoe" with an image of a shoe. I have been working in jQuery and using the documentation to make what I already did below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var newText = $("body").text().split(" "); 
    $.each(newText, function(index, value) {
        if (newText[index] === "shoe") {
            newText[index] = "<img src='http://.../shoe.png' alt='shoe'>";
        }
    });
    var altText = newText.join("</span> <span>");
    $("body").html(altText);
});
```

I see what I am doing: ripping the text out and then shoving back in.  But I am at a loss of what I should use.

I am aware of the `replaceWith()` function and I suppose that is the right one to use.  But how do I get to the "shoe" words in the first place?

Thanks

Comment: Might check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541070/how-can-i-do-a-jquery-swear-word-bad-word-filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if jQuery helps a lot here.  You are best off probably just doing a replace on the full html... with some (potentially bad) notes and caveats.

1) Ideally, you would only use `text()` via jQuery, but after you have the text, you have no easy way of putting it back.  `this is <span>my</span> dog` => `this is my <img src="dog.jpg">`.. losing your span.

2) Replacing on the full html would be bad if your html tags contain the words you are replacing!! `<div id="dog">` => `<div id="<img src="dog.jpg">">` Ugh!

3) Use word boundary delimiters `\bshoe\b` in your regular expression to match on whole words only to prevent: `catastrophe` => `<img src="cat.jpg">astrophe`

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/7cajW/

**BETTER**:

I coded a better solution, using lower-level code based on `jquery.highlight`.

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/jRebk/3/

It adds a function prototype for `.rebus(wordMap, [caseSensitive], [useWordBoundaries])`, where the defaults are false and true, respectively, for the latter two.

Usage:

```
var myRebus = {
    "shoe": "http://i54.tinypic.com/254zjgy.png",
    "hat" : "http://i55.tinypic.com/11iicgg.png",
    "dog" : "http://i55.tinypic.com/287p11k.png",
};

$('body').rebus(myRebus);
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to look into customizing this text [**highlighting plug-in**](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html). The [**source code**](http://johannburkard.de/resources/Johann/jquery.highlight-3.js) is actually pretty simple. Take a look at this section:

```
// --- snip ---
var spannode = document.createElement('span');
spannode.className = 'highlight';
var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
// --- snip ---
```

The code creates a new span element, takes the matched string, inserts it into the new span, then replaces the original matched string with the new span element.

For your situation, instead of creating a `<span>`, create an `<img>`. And instead of adding back in the found string, look up the appropriate image URL in a map of your own construction. So you'd have something like this:

```
var rebus = {
  shoe : '/images/shoe.jpg',
  sock : '/images/sock.jpg',
  spats : '/images/spats.jpg'
}
```

And in the code, before the `appendChild` line, you'd have something like this:

```
var middleclone = rebus[ middleclone.data.toLowerCase() ];
```

This is all from a quick skim of the code, and untested, but it seems like you should be able to strip out the highlighting pieces and drop in some substitution code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would work as extension but i'd try it that way:
http://jsfiddle.net/wSCAx/

```
var b = document.body;
var t = b.innerHTML;
b.innerHTML = t.replace(/shoe/g,'<img src=""/>');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried this out and while it kept most elements intact,...it oddly managed to throw some around.  I'll keep exploring this.

Answer (score 0):

is this way valid for you?:

```
$(function(){
    var sHtmlText = $('body').html();
    sHtmlText = sHtmlText.replace(/shoe/g, "<img src='http://.../shoe.png' alt='shoe'>");
    $('body').html(sHtmlText);
})
```

Explain: just get the full raw html in a string variable, and apply directly the replace statement and put the correct string again on body tag. i think that you dont need to split and iterate all the possible words in the html.

if you can do this dynamically on the server side, i think that is better and you could prevent some kind of plage flicking or strage behaviours on this way!!