# JavaScript Wiki Chat Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if anyone could give me some help on this. I do some admin stuff at a wiki, and was hoping to add a filter, to remove any inapropriate language. I did some research, because I'm not really up on JavaScript, and found the following code:

```
 /**
 * Chat message filter.
 *
 * @description Filters banned links and censors words
 *
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
    var regexp = new Array();
        regexp[0] = new RegExp("special:(chat|logout)", "gi");
        regexp[1] = new RegExp("yolo", "gi");
        regexp[2] = new RegExp("swag", "gi");
    $('[name="message"]').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 2) {
            for (var i = 0; i < regexp.length; i++) {
                this.value = this.value.replace(regexp[i], "");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Anyway, I added it to the wikia, and it doesn't seem to be working. As I don't know Javascript, I was wondering if anyone would be able to point out any errors that may be preventing it from running properly?

Comment: Can you give a small HTML snippet of a piece that you are trying to filter?  It looks like you're trying to select all html tags that have the name "message" but I'm not sure if that's what you mean to do without seeing some HTML

Comment: What do you expect `$('[name="message"]')` to be, and when will that element be available?

Comment: What key do you expect to have the key code `2`???

Comment: is $('[name="message"]') a textarea by any chance?

Comment: Anyway, $(this).val() would work in any case

Comment: This word-filter looks useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4541116/975097

Comment: Sorry guys, I have literally no idea what the program does, I just got it off a friend who claimed it worked. So, I can't really answer any of the questions. Thanks for the responses anyway.