# Prevent user to write specific words on <textarea>

Tags: javascript

I've been watching a tutorial from developphp guy from youtube. I want to avoid people to write bad words on my text area from my form.

But I want to prevent them from writting several words, not only one, this tutorial doesn't explain that and I'm trying to find a way without succees, can someone explain me?

this is the actual javascript

HTML

```
<textarea class="ta" id="ta" name="ta" onkeyup="clean('ta')" onkeydown="clean('ta')" placeholder="A good word for a good word"></textarea>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function clean(el){
var textfield = document.getElementById(el);
var regex = /fuck/gi;
if(textfield.value.search(regex) > -1) {
    textfield.value = textfield.value.replace(regex, "");
    }
}
</script>
```

Thanks for your time guys!

Comment: google "regular expressions"

Comment: See this posting which uses JQuery search and replace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541070/how-can-i-do-a-jquery-swear-word-bad-word-filter

Comment: Don't forget to validate the input on the server side, javascript can be disabled! Doing it in php: `$validated_input = preg_replace('/badword1|badword2|badwordn/gi, '', $input')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build your regex with multiple | (pipe) separated words:

```
textfield.value = textfield.value.replace(/badword1|badword2|badwordn/gi , "" );
```

Comment: hi @stacker but I want to include more words to the var regex to remove not only /fuck/ word but also others?:)

Comment: i like the look of this one

Answer (score 1):

Well the easiest way to do this (for me) is to probably use a library like jQuery to watch for key press on the text box.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<textarea id="mytextArea" style="width:200px; height:300px"></textarea>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mytextArea').keyup(function() {
    var textBoxValue = $(this).val();
    console.log(textBoxValue);

    var forbidden = [
      'fuck',
      'shit'
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < forbidden.length; i++) {
      if(textBoxValue.search(forbidden[i]) > -1) {
        textBoxValue = textBoxValue.replace(forbidden[i], '');
      }
    }

    $(this).val(textBoxValue);
  });
});
```

Try it here https://jsfiddle.net/t1p27hv4/

Obviously you still have to think about things like 'f   uck' which the forbidden array would not handle so your regex approach could be a good idea to explore but hopefully this will get you started.

Also, this has probably been done already so google it.