# Why does this regexp throw a javascript error

Tags: javascript, regex

```
regexp = new RegExp(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b);

Error:66SyntaxError: Unrecognized token '\'
```

Comment: You should also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966535/javascript-regexp-and-boundaries if you are using word boundaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When calling `new RegExp()` you must pass the pattern as a string. Enclose it in quotes.

```
var regexp = new RegExp('\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b');
```

You could also create it as using the special `/pattern/` delimited syntax, in which it is *not* quoted:

```
var regexp = /[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}/;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the regex should be:

```
/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/
```